# Jump links and positioning via style="padding-top: 100px;

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a website that uses Jump Links to move between page elements (it's an interactive User Guide), and all works ok on Firefox, IE, and Edge, but Chrome and Opera ignore the 'padding'.

As the website has a fixed menu bar, this means the jump link location vanishes under the bar on Chrome and Opera.

The simple code I am using for the jump link offset is:

```
<a id="namexxx" style="padding-top: 100px;"></a>
```

What can I do to make this work with Chroma and Opera?

All the solutions I have been able to find via search do not answer the difference issue between the different browsers.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you share a code sample via codepen or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Padding isn't a suitable approach to repositioning an element in this way, because it would increase the size of the element itself. In the case of a link, you'd effectively be creating a larger link area, with the space above the link becoming clickable too.

You'd be better off using `margin-top` which would move the element down the page. Depending on the rest of your markup, you might need to set `display: inline-block;` on the link element too.